# Flutter how to show array data in text widget by for loop

Tags: flutter

I have simple list in which some string are available. I just to need to show all strings in Text widget by for loop

I try like this

```
List datesData = [{
  '09:00 am - 10:00 am',
  '10:00 am - 11:00 am',
  '11:00 am - 12:00 am',
  '12:00 am - 01:00 am',
  '01:00 am - 02:00 am',
  '02:00 am - 03:00 am',
  '03:00 am - 04:00 am',
  '04:00 am - 05:00 am'
}];

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
     Container(
       child: Text(datesData(i)),
     );
}
```

ITs show error in datesData `The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.`

Also in don't want to define length of for lopp like  `for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)` i need to check it automatically that it has 8 strings.

Comment: do you want a list of text widgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the indexed data of the date array. There is an incorrect usage of parentheses. You need to use square brackets to get an index of array. It should look like this:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    Container(
     child: Text(datesDate[i]),
      );
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, you can use this widget list inside a column. Now, it will look like this:

```
  List datesData = [
    
      '09:00 am - 10:00 am',
      '10:00 am - 11:00 am',
      '11:00 am - 12:00 am',
      '12:00 am - 01:00 am',
      '01:00 am - 02:00 am',
      '02:00 am - 03:00 am',
      '03:00 am - 04:00 am',
      '04:00 am - 05:00 am'
    
  ];

  List<Widget> textWidgetList = List<Widget>(); // Here we defined a list of widget!

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      textWidgetList.add(
        Container(
          child: Text(datesData[i]),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: textWidgetList,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: And how can i show it in scaffold widget ? Mean i am using for loop before returning scaffold how can i show this now in scaffold widget ?

Comment: you need to learn flutter basics first. You cannot randomly execute for loop anywhere. Everything in flutter is a Widget, So I suggest you read more about widgets because you'll need some kind of listing widget to contain all of your text widgets. When building the list widget you can map your array elements to text widgets and pass them as children.

Comment: @Akash Sarode is right. And I edited the answer with some more code.

Comment: @Akif its showing error now RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Comment: Of course, that is my bad. Removed curly braces between the string array.

Answer (score 3):

```
make it more dynamic
```

```html
 for(int i = 0; i < datesData.length; i++){
    Container(
     child: Text(datesDate[i]),
      );
    }
```

Update You can show with listview.builder

```html
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List data = [
    '09:00 am - 10:00 am',
    '10:00 am - 11:00 am',
    '11:00 am - 12:00 am',
    '12:00 am - 01:00 am',
    '01:00 am - 02:00 am',
    '02:00 am - 03:00 am',
    '03:00 am - 04:00 am',
    '04:00 am - 05:00 am'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
            return new Text(data[index]);
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toList` which makes easier and also use `indexOf` if you need index

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DateDataWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List datesData = [
    '09:00 am - 10:00 am',
    '10:00 am - 11:00 am',
    '11:00 am - 12:00 am',
    '12:00 am - 01:00 am',
    '01:00 am - 02:00 am',
    '02:00 am - 03:00 am',
    '03:00 am - 04:00 am',
    '04:00 am - 05:00 am'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          child: Column(
        children: datesData.map((date) {
          int index = datesData.indexOf(date); // use index if you want.
          print(index);
          return Text(date);
        }).toList(),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use `int index` if you need.

Answer (score 1):

try this code on [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List data = [
    '09:00 am - 10:00 am',
    '10:00 am - 11:00 am',
    '11:00 am - 12:00 am',
    '12:00 am - 01:00 am',
    '01:00 am - 02:00 am',
    '02:00 am - 03:00 am',
    '03:00 am - 04:00 am',
    '04:00 am - 05:00 am'
  ];
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: data.map((element) => ListTile(title: Text(element))).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```